# What do these double parentheses do in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the book `secrets of the js ninja`, and very often I saw code like this

```
(function(){
  something here;
  })();
```

Why do we need to enclose the function within parentheses and why do we add one more pair of parentheses after that?

Comment: Yes the function keyword returns the anonymous function, the () at the end invokes that function. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091289/javascript-anonymous-function-call) for the same issue.

Comment: @CrazyTrain http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: @RoyiNamir: But you're the one saying that it's better. You must have some reason to believe this. I did try http://jslint.com but won't give me a reason either.

Comment: @CrazyTrain better via validation. ( the correct word is "referred")

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Nah, the correct word is "irrelevant". jsLint imposes arbitrary restrictions without any rational reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
(function(){
  alert('hello');
})();
```

although it is a function is it called automatically so you dont/can't call it manually

These can be useful for `for` loops like so

This will fail because i would be equal to 9 after 5 seconds

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   window.setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i);
   }, 5000)
}
```

So you could do this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   (function(a){
      window.setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(a);
      }, 5000)
   })(i);
}
```

Also good for creating a "private" scope like this

```
(function(){
   var test = 'hello';
   console.log( test ); // 'hello'
}());

   console.log( test ); // 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 6):

Its a self calling function, that invokes its self as the script finishes loading. You can call it without arguments, or you can add arguments to it such as `window` or `document`.

You use it in a way that jQuery use it:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    // jQuery code
})(window);
```

An (almost) alternative syntax to do the same thing:

```
! function( window, undefined ){
    // some code…
}(window);
```

Read more at: http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/

Comment: I'd prefer the `!` operator since it's a prefix unary operator, which means it'll never try to operate on some leading expression, like the `()` can.

Answer (score 3):

The last set of parentheses causes the function to execute immediately. A function is created and executed without ever assigning it anywhere. The reason one might wrap their code in a function like this is to encapsulate code. Take this for example:

```
var myVar = 'whatever';
function shout() { alert(myVar); }
```

Here, `myVar` and `shout` have just become global variables. You can open up your console and type `window.myVar` or `window.shout` and you'll be able to access and change those variables. By wrapping it in a function, those variables remain local to the outer function:

```
(function() {
    var myVar = 'whatever';
    function shout() { alert(myVar); }
})();
```

`window.myVar` and `window.shout` are undefined. The only exist inside that function.

The pattern is also used to create a closure around local variables. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Answer (score 0):

Self invoking function, basically it calls itself stright away.

Used normally to pass in a variable like jQuery to insure that `$` is truly the jQuery object!

```
(function($){
    // $ now is equal to jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It runs the function you just created.  The reason to do this is that it encloses all of the code you write within a new scope.  This means when you define `vars` and `functions`, they will be kept within the scope of that `function()` you just created.

In short, it encapsulates code.