# how does javascript !function() { } work

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

How does this structure work when the function is anonymous?

```
  !function() {             
            .
            .
            .

  }();
```

Comment: returned value NOT ed, `!false`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091289/javascript-anonymous-function-call, which, in turn, seems to be a triple duplicate. )

Comment: The anonymous function is executed, but the return value is not used anywhere.

Comment: There's no test for existence. The return value is negated and discarded.

Answer (score 2):

With a return value.. you negate that with `!`

```
var x=!function(){return false}();
console.log(x);
// true
```

double negation

```
var pizza='pizza';
var x=!!function(){return pizza}();
console.log(x);
// true

// returns true if pizza is defined, not 'pizza'
// returns false if pizza is ''.
```

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/9shzF/1/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much as with any other thing. The anonymous function is autoexecuted, therefore returns a value, and the value is negated.