# Confusion about auto-run functions

Tags: javascript, function

I know what auto-running functions are, I use them very often in both Node.js and simple JavaScript. But I still don't understand something.

I kind of know why the following works

```
(function () {/* Stuff */})();
```

But I seriously have no idea why the following works...

```
(function () {/* Stuff */}());
```

...while the following doesn't...

```
function () {/* Stuff */}();
```

...but this also works...

```
!function () {/* Stuff */}(); // The "!" can be any valid expression
```

Can I get a detailed explanation?

Comment: Duplicate of [!function(){ }() vs (function(){ })()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8305915/218196), [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/218196), [Javascript anonymous function call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9091289/218196), [Explain JavaScript's encapsulated anonymous function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/218196) and others.

Comment: *"The "!" can be any valid expression"* That's incorrect. `!` needs to be a unary operator.

Answer (score -1):

If it is javascript

```js
(function () {console.log("hi");})();
```

This is an Immediately invocable function expression, which mean definition followed by invocation, so as it is getting called immediately it works

```js
function () {console.log("hi")}();
```

This will throw an error ,because definition is followed by braces,if you want to invoke it make it an IIFE

```js
!function () {console.log("hi")}();
```

This is because, if you put a unary operator before the function declaration, you need not add  closing braces, and it chops off one character of the code.

Hope it helps

Comment: You don't really explain why any of these work / don't work.